# Unable to implement join properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out

(book_id, branch_id, total_copies, number_available)

Here is the schema:
[image]

Here is as far I have gone:

```
SELECT
  TITLE,
  A.BOOK_ID,
  A.BRANCH_NAME,
  A.BRANCH_ID,
  NO_OF_COPIES,
  COUNT(BOOK_LOANS.BOOK_ID) AS NUM_OUT,
  NO_OF_COPIES - COUNT(BOOK_LOANS.BOOK_ID) AS NUM_AVAIL,
  AUTHOR_NAME                                      
FROM
  (SELECT
    TITLE,
    BOOK.BOOK_ID,
    BOOK_COPIES.BRANCH_ID,
    BRANCH_NAME,
    NO_OF_COPIES,
    BOOK_AUTHORS.AUTHOR_NAME                                          
  FROM
    BOOK,
    BOOK_COPIES,
    LIBRARY_BRANCH,
    BOOK_AUTHORS                                          
  WHERE
    BOOK_COPIES.BOOK_ID=BOOK.BOOK_ID 
    AND BOOK_AUTHORS.BOOK_ID = BOOK.BOOK_ID 
    AND (
      BOOK.TITLE LIKE :title 
      OR BOOK.BOOK_ID = :book_id 
      OR BOOK_AUTHORS.AUTHOR_NAME LIKE :author_name
    )                                          
    AND BOOK_COPIES.BRANCH_ID=LIBRARY_BRANCH.BRANCH_ID) AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BOOK_LOANS 
    ON A.BOOK_ID=BOOK_LOANS.BOOK_ID 
    AND A.BRANCH_ID=BOOK_LOANS.BRANCH_ID 
GROUP BY
  A.BOOK_ID,
  A.BRANCH_ID
```

But the problem I am encountering is, since BOOK_AUTHORS table has multiple authors for a single book. So I am able to understand that joining only on book_id of BOOK and BOOK_AUTHORS while I should be able to completely using the both book_id and author_name.

So its returning the count 2 times for a single entry in book_loans.

e.g. If a book with book_id lets say 1234 is checked out once, and it has total copies of 2, so it should return remaining copies as 1. But its returning 0.

Please help me understand how to fix this.

Note: I am using php prepare statement.

Comment: as far as schema is concerned i think there should be a table called `authors_master` having two columns `author_id,author_name` so that it can be mapped to book using a table `book_author` having only two columns `book_id,author_id`

Comment: That might be a solution, but that's what I have been given to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't pay attention on you query (too complicated to me),

- `COUNT(DISTINCT BOOK_LOANS.BOOK_ID)` rather than `COUNT(BOOK_LOANS.BOOK_ID)`. If you query works well except its count, DISTINCT is helpful.
- performance matters. I guess inline view is too complicate. I wonder if changed like this

  ```
  SELECT
      DISTINCT BOOK.BOOK_ID
  FROM
      BOOK INNER JOIN BOOK_AUTHORS USING(BOOK_ID)                                     
  WHERE
        BOOK.TITLE LIKE :title 
        OR BOOK.BOOK_ID = :book_id 
        OR BOOK_AUTHORS.AUTHOR_NAME LIKE :author_name
  ```
- Then final query looks like this

  ```
  SELECT
  TITLE,
  BOOK.BOOK_ID,
  LIBRARY_BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME,
  LIBRARY_BRANCH.BRANCH_ID,
  BOOK_COPIES.NO_OF_COPIES,
  COUNT(distinct BOOK_LOANS.BOOK_ID) AS NUM_OUT,
  BOOK_COPIES.NO_OF_COPIES - COUNT(distinct BOOK_LOANS.BOOK_ID) AS NUM_AVAIL,
  AUTHOR_NAME  

  FROM
    (
      SELECT
          DISTINCT BOOK.BOOK_ID
      FROM
          BOOK,
          BOOK_AUTHORS                                          
      WHERE
            BOOK.TITLE LIKE :title 
            OR BOOK.BOOK_ID = :book_id 
            OR BOOK_AUTHORS.AUTHOR_NAME LIKE :author_name
    ) AS A 
  INNER JOIN BOOK USING(BOOK_ID)
  INNER JOIN BOOK_AUTHORS USING (BOOK_ID)
  INNER JOIN BOOK_COPIES USING(BOOK_ID) 
  INNER JOIN LIBRARY_BRANCH USING(BRANCH_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    BOOK_LOANS 
      ON BOOK.BOOK_ID=BOOK_LOANS.BOOK_ID 
      AND LIBRARY_BRANCH.BRANCH_ID=BOOK_LOANS.BRANCH_ID 
  GROUP BY
    BOOK.BOOK_ID,
    LIBRARY_BRANCH.BRANCH_ID,
    LIBRARY_BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME,
    BOOK_COPIES.NO_OF_COPIES,
    AUTHOR_NAME
  ```

Comment: Corrected the typos but `A.BRANCH_ID = BOOK_LOANS.BRANCH_ID` won't work because A doesn't have `BRANCH_ID` in it.

Comment: @user2961121 sorry. fixed. it was copy&paste.

Comment: @user2961121 "two rows are returned" this can not be eliminated. When 1 book has 3 authors, SELECT always return 3 rows. I think you need to make 2 queries, one for book & loan info, one for author info.

Comment: Oh ok, I need to find out a way to distinctly display them then.

Comment: I succeeded!
But could you explain me what you did?

Thanxxxxx a lot!

Comment: searching on author_name is returning every row in the joined table.

Comment: @user2961121 Oops, sorry, I made mistake. updated my answer. ("FROM BOOK, BOOK_AUTHORS" => "FROM BOOK INNER JOIN BOOK_AUTHORS USING(BOOK_ID)") this is why people like sqlFiddle.